# PHP Form Validation: Unique Submission

Tags: php, mysql

Checking if a user submitted 'username' is already in database:

This always returns "Username is unique!"

```
$check = $pdo->query("SELECT username FROM users");
$result = $check->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(!in_array($_POST['username'], $result))
{
    echo "Username is unique! <br>";        
}
else 
{
    echo "Username already exists. <br>";
}
```

So my question is, what's wrong with this? And also, is there a better way to go about it? Thanks.

Comment: Change your SQL little bit `SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?`

Comment: `->fetchAll()` returns a multidimensional array -> ie. `array(0=>array('username'=>'user1'), 1=>array('username'=>'user2'), ...)` so `in_array()` does not work in your current format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ask the DB if you have the value already. Something like

```
$check = $pdo->prepare("SELECT username FROM users where username = ?");
$check->execute(array($_POST['username']));
if($row = $check->fetch()) {
     echo "Username already exists. <br>";
} else {
     echo "Username is unique! <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So, fetchAll() will return an associative array i.e.

```
array(
  0 => array(
    'username' => 'foo',
  ),
  1 => array(
    'username' => 'bar',
  ),
  // ...
)
```

The in_array() function won't traverse recursively into each sub array, so the check will be done against each top level array. You can fix this by changing fetchAll() to fetchCol() which will return a flattened array i.e.

```
array(
  0 => 'foo',
  1 => 'bar',
)
```

It's probably not a great idea doing it this way because you're storing all your usernames in memory and searching this data. The other suggestions posted here about using a prepared statement to pull out a single username if one exists is the better way to go.